# Continuously Fixing Same Mercurial Merge Issues

Tags: mercurial

My co-worker and I are working on a project and we are using mercurial + bitbucket.

We are experiencing problems when one of us pulls from bitbucket and merge. For instance, after I pull from bitbucket with `hg pull --rebase`, I have to

- remove files that were removed in previous commits
- modify files that were modified in previous commits
- move files/folders that were moved in previous commits

He does `hg pull` followed with `hg merge` and gets the same results as me.

**What are we doing wrong?**

Besides rebase/merge, we work the same

- work, work, work
- pull rebase/merge
- fix merge issues
- push

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that you're rebasing changesets that have already been pushed. Rebase modifies history, and unless you really know what you're doing you should only rebase changesets that have never been shared to another repository.

If you are using Mercurial 2.1 or later it has support for [phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases). When phases are working rebase will only allow rebasing of draft and secret changesets, not public ones.

In general, I'd advise you to use merging rather than rebasing.